# Seguridad al Consultar BD de un servidor a una app

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un aplicativo móvil el cual se conecta a la base de datos de un servidor. El problema es la seguridad de la base de datos: según mi investigación la mejor manera de conectar la base de datos es con un api rest con php, el cual sería así:

```php
<?php

$conexion =mysqli_connect('localhost','usuario','contraseña','basededatos');
if(!$conexion)
{
    echo "error en conexion";
}

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$direccion =$_POST['direccion'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuario(nombre,correo,direccion) values('$nombre','$correo','$direccion')";
$resultado =mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

if($resultado){
    echo "datos insertados";
}else{
    echo "datos error";
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

El cual se subiría al servidor. Lo que me preocupa es que ya que la contraseña de la base datos está puesta, cualquiera podría hacer una enumeración de directorios y descubrir dicho archivo y hacer consultas y hasta ingresar datos.

> La duda que tengo es cómo puedo evitar eso, cómo podría cambiar para que sea más seguro o cómo se podría hacer un api para la consulta de la base datos más segura.

Comment: si te preocupa eso deberias tu hacer una api y trabajar con objteos Json en lugar de datos directamente de la base, investiga mas sobre API REST

Comment: El problema con respecto al código que expones es el riesgo de *inyección SQL*, el cual se resuelve usando consultas preparadas. Dicho eso, cualquiera que conozca la URL, o un bot, podrá ingresar datos indiscriminadamente. Para evitar eso debes programar una API o servicio REST que verifique que el usuario tiene permisos para acceder al servicio, mediante tokens, o claves de API o de otro modo, pero ese es otro asunto... Debes decidir qué tipo de seguridad usarás, escribir tu código y si tienes algún problema concreto con respecto a ese código entonces te ayudaremos.

Comment: Dos problemas distintos: uno es la vulnerabilidad de tus consultas que ya expuso @A.Cedano; el otro, es la exposición de las credenciales, ¿a "cualquiera"? no. ¿A clientes web? No mientras funcione el intérprete de php, ¿A otros que accedan el sistema operativo? tal vez, depende de los permisos. Se estila mucho guardar los datos de autenticación en archivos -separados- de configuración, no accesibles desde fuera (http) y con acceso restringido, primordialmente legibles para el usuario del servidor web y ocultos para todos los demás, incluyendo otros desarrolladores o intrusos al SO.

Comment: Tu duda parece ser que "cualquiera podría hacer una enumeración de directorios" y eso no tiene relación directa con la conexión a la base de datos, es un tema de seguridad de acceso a las carpetas, lo cual debería solucionarse con una correcta configuración del servidor web. Coincido con la puntualización de @Sal, los ficheros sensibles guárdalos fuera de la carpeta web (generalmente www o htdocs)